# Simple Async Google Maps initializer with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, angular.js, promise, google-maps

Here is a simple reusable `AngularJS` `factory` I came up with to initialize Google Maps Asynchronously, which somehow does not seem to be supported by major libraries (see below):

Following Google's guidelines I am using **global** callback function (which seems to be unavoidable harm), that resolves a dummy `promise`, which is the only API returned.

Then maps can be loaded anywhere by simply calling

```
Initializer.mapsInitialized.
    .then(function(){
        map = new google.maps.Map(element, options);
    });
```

Below is the code. Any critics, potential flaws, drawbacks, violation of best practices is welcome!

```
// Google async initializer needs global function, so we use $window
angular.module('GoogleMapsInitializer')
    .factory('Initializer', function($window, $q){

        // maps loader deferred object
        var mapsDefer = $q.defer();

        // Google's url for async maps initialization accepting callback function
        var asyncUrl = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=';

        // async loader
        var asyncLoad = function(asyncUrl, callbackName) {
          var script = document.createElement('script');
          //script.type = 'text/javascript';
          script.src = asyncUrl + callbackName;
          document.body.appendChild(script);
        };

        // callback function - resolving promise after maps successfully loaded
        $window.googleMapsInitialized = function () {
            mapsDefer.resolve();
        };

        // loading google maps
        asyncLoad(asyncUrl, 'googleMapsInitialized');

        return {

            // usage: Initializer.mapsInitialized.then(callback)
            mapsInitialized : mapsDefer.promise
        };
    })
```

Most major libraries built for Google Maps seem to use the standard script tag

```
<script src='//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js'></script>
```

which is, however, blocking, may result in delays, and makes the page unsuitable for offline testing.

On another note, library such as `script.js` async loader, does not seem to work with this particular script.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I like it,

you could clean up the commented out code and possibly replace

```
    $window.googleMapsInitialized = function () {
        mapsDefer.resolve();
    };
```

with

```
    $window.googleMapsInitialized = mapsDefer.resolve;
```

Personally, I would re-arrange the code a tiny bit, keep the URL completely on top,
keep `asyncLoad` and the call closer together. Keep the declaration of `mapsDefer` and the resolving function closer.

```
// Google async initializer needs global function, so we use $window
angular.module('GoogleMapsInitializer')
.factory('Initializer', function($window, $q){

    //Google's url for async maps initialization accepting callback function
    var asyncUrl = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=',
        mapsDefer = $q.defer();

    //Callback function - resolving promise after maps successfully loaded
    $window.googleMapsInitialized = mapsDefer.resolve; // removed ()

    //Async loader
    var asyncLoad = function(asyncUrl, callbackName) {
      var script = document.createElement('script');
      //script.type = 'text/javascript';
      script.src = asyncUrl + callbackName;
      document.body.appendChild(script);
    };
    //Start loading google maps
    asyncLoad(asyncUrl, 'googleMapsInitialized');

    //Usage: Initializer.mapsInitialized.then(callback)
    return {
        mapsInitialized : mapsDefer.promise
    };
})
```